# Ignore network drive in System list

Tags: file-browser

Is there a way to ignore mapped network drives in Blender when saving/loading? I am using Blender at work and my work laptop has multiple drives mapped. When I disconnect from the corporate network (so that the network drives are essentially disconnected but still mapped) I get long pauses, sometimes up to 30 seconds, when saving/loading as Blender is presumably waiting for each network drive connection to timeout.

This is what I see in my System pane:

[image: System list]

I need to ignore everything except C drive. I could disconnect those drives in Windows but then I would need to remap them again.

Appreciate any insight. Thanks!